# How to display alert and confirmation if back browser button has been clicked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, browser

I am creating an exam application mainly using php and jquery. At the moment the application has these pages in order to for the user to create an exam:

- **Create.php** (teacher creates the exam details e.g. date, time, duration,
  subject, number of questions, total marks etc)
- **QandA.php** (teacher creates questions and answers for the exam)
- **Marks.php** (teacher sets up marks for each correct answer(s) per question)
- **Penalty.php** (teacher selects whether their exam will contain penalty marks or not)
- **Finish.php** (simply states that your creation of your exam is complete)

Now the application works fine but there is something I have realized. As this application is run on a browser, the user is able to at anytime click on the Browser back button. This is going to cause big problems because if I am half way in completing the creation of the exam but click on the browser back button, then I will lose my exam creation progress or worse I am able to do one of the pages again. This could mean the database which stores the details will contain a half complete exam or an exam which could contain more information than required.

So this is what I am thinking of doing but I do not know if first of all if it is possible and if it is best practice to do so:

- If user clicks on a back browser button while on any of the 4 pages above (except for finish.php) then a confirmation box appears stating "if you go back to previous page then you will lose all your current progress and be sent to menu page (menu.php)
- If user clicks on OK in the confirmation box, then it will navigate user to the menu.php page and it will also by AJAX navigate to another php page (deleteentry.php) where it will delete the exam details from the database)
- If user clicks on Cancel then they can continue on current page no problem
- If user clicks on back browser button while on finish.php page, then it will display an alert stating "you can't go back, your exax has been sucessfully completed, you will be navigated back to menu page" And all it will do is navigate user to menu.php page and thats it, no ajax to call or anything)

My question then is that

1. Is the above ideas a suitable solution to be able to tackle this problem
2. How should the code can be written to determine when the back browser button has been pressed depending on the page it was pressed on and be able to perform the commands it is able to perform? Also need to know how the AJAX can be written to navigate to deleteentry.php page in background.

Thank You very much

Comment: The only thing unsuitable about your question, is your question.

Comment: @Eritrea Can I ask what is unsuitable about my question, I will make changes if it needs changes

Comment: the best i can offer is, use session.

Comment: @itachi what do you mean by using sessions? how will that determine i the user has clicked on a back button, or a forward button or a refresh?

Comment: the procedure is simple. If he submits, store the value in the session. Your current setup can not give you the result as you expected. If you use session, the user clicks back/front button, it does not matter. value will not change.

Comment: @itachi somebody else mentioned this. I was wondering though what happens if lets say i create questions and answers in the `QandA.php` and then I submit the form and navigate to the next page, then by going back to the `QandA.php` page by clicking on the back browser button I fill in the questions and answers again and then submit the form again, would that mean the session is either A. Current question and answers replaces previous submitted questions and answers or B. Will the sessions contain both the previous and current questions and answers?

Comment: depends what you want. You can replace them or kepp both the new and old value. [**this link**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) for more info.

Comment: @itachi So does that mean lets say I replace the values in a session, I need the database to be able to change so that it can update the database to get rid of the old values and replace it with the new values. Will that be a good way to go about it?

Comment: `$_SESSION` is an array(). On each subsequent submission, enter the value as key. And on Final submission, insert the all values in the database. Try some simple examples of `session` 1st.

Comment: @itachi I think I know where I have went wrong. What I have done is that for each page, when the teacher submits a page, it does an insert into the database. E.g create.php has been submitted, it submits create.php details into database, QandA.php has been submitted so insert QandATable.php details into the db etc. What you are saying I should do is once all of the pages have been completed, then submit all of the details from all of the pages into the database. That is what you are saying right?

Comment: @itachi Thanks for your comments  I have marked each of your comments individually so you can get some points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to answer the question in your title:

> How to display alert and confirmation if back browser button has been clicked

You can't know if the "back" button was clicked or if the page was refreshed or just page changed ->

The `onunload` event will handle all of those cases.

Comment: I have a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/CDSAF/ which I created whcih kind of does what I want it to do but I want to know that is this method ok? it is using onbeforeload but problem is url seems a little dodgy when clicking on "Stay on page".

Comment: Ok cool, I will go on with this method. I will research on AJAX and hopefully it will state how to navigate to other php scripts in background. But what i want to ask you Neal as a person who I am guessing have creted a lot of web applications. IF you had a simple php application but you don't want the browser buttons or refresh to get in your way and you want your app working on all browsers, how would you tackle the problem so that the browser buttons don't affect your application?

Comment: somebody else mentioned this. I was wondering though what happens if lets say i create questions and answers in the `QandA.php` and then I submit the form and navigate to the next page, then by going back to the `QandA.php` page by clicking on the back browser button I fill in the questions and answers again and then submit the form again, would that mean the session is either A. Current question and answers replaces previous submitted questions and answers or B. Will the sessions contain both the previous and current questions and answers?